# create element and drag it with one click with jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I know about jQuery UI and draggable and droppable, in my case I don't have any element because I don't know client how many item needed, I want when client click with mouse `onmousedown` element created, then without releasing mouse, and `onmousemove` element moving around page until droppable zone, when mouse release `onmouseup` if element in droppable zone, do something and if not in droppable zone element will be removed, I can create, remove, and move element when mouse release first time and click again on created element, I want move it with one click and mouse move;

```js
let flag_create_element = false;
let flag_mouse_down = false;
$('.btn_create').off('mousedown').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    flag_mouse_down = true;
    flag_create_element = true;
    let created_option_title = '<div class="new-element-added"></div>';
    if (flag_create_element){
        $('body').append(created_option_title);
        $('.new-element-added').draggable();
    }
});
$('body').off('mousemove').on('mousemove',function (event) {
    $(this).on('mousemove', createAndMoveElement(event));
}).off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function () {
    flag_mouse_down = false;
    flag_create_element = false;
    //$('.new-element-added').remove();
});

function createAndMoveElement(event) {
    if (flag_mouse_down){
        $('.new-element-added').draggable();
    }
    flag_create_element = false;
}


$('#droppable_zone').droppable({
    drop: function () {
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

```css
#droppable_zone{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin: auto;
width: 50vw;
min-height: 50vh;
background-color: bisque;
}
.btn_create{
position: absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
width: 45px;
height: 45px;
background-color: green;
}

.new-element-added{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
display: block;
z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<article id="droppable_zone">


</article>

<button type="button" class="btn_create">
<i class="fas fa-plus align-middle font-15"></i>
</button>
```